# can you help me about big o?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I need help about big O.
I'm not sure.

```
while (i<n){

   while(j=n){
      j++;
   }//this is I think n*(n+1)

   i++;//(n+1)

}//n
```

I need to tell me someone how calculate this if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put the question correctly?

It looks like the program will newer enter the inner loop or just enter it once. If the code is correct I would say it is just O(n).